# How to prevent newline after subsection and align the paragraph of condition?

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-breaking, alignment, subsection

In my project

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc, vietnam}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Definition}
A Galileo spacetime is a pair $(M,F)$ such that
\\ (1)\indent For all $(x,t),\,(y,t)\in F$, the length of duration of time between any two event $p,q\in M$ is invariant to both $x$ and $y$, which mean  
\\ (2)\indent ...

\end{document}
```

I want to prevent the newline after the subsection without changing anything of the subsection's name's font. And then, I want to align the paragraph "(1) For all ..." such that the next line is indented to be in line with with the word "For all" of the previous line, and the paragraph "(2) .." is done similarly. How can I do this ? Thanks.

Comment: You should not abuse \\ for line breaks and instead of manually numbering your items, have a look a the enumitem package. If you don't want a line break after the subsection heading, use a `\paragraph` instead.

Comment: First of why are you using ``\\`` in the text? You should never need that. Use a proper list, for example enumerate (which is easily configurable using the `enumitem` package)

Comment: You might want to read [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use ```\paragraph{ }``` and my project goes error, is there anything else can I do ?

Comment: @PermQi Seems to work fine: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hpczrwmnkztr#bf0750

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want more space between the number and the statement, like equal to the length space of ```\indent```. How can I do that ?

Comment: @PermQi By using enumitem.  The package documentation is at https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en, Overleaf has some documentation at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists#Using_the_enumitem_package_to_modify_and_create_lists

Comment: @Teepeemm I still yet to get your point.  [This](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bmjsqbwmcjxs#af5334) is when I use enumitem.  I don't know how to add more space betwwen "(1)" and  "For all ..."

Comment: Do not ignore compilation errors.  Documentation for both enumitem and enumerate say that enumitem supercedes, so don't load enumerate.  Have you read section 3.2 of the enumitem documenation?